# Looping through list of lists which contains of 2 items each

Tags: iteration

```
list_a=[[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
```

I'm given list like this. As seen list_a's elements are in form of [a,b].
How do I iterate over a only or b only?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: In this list, the elements are in form of [a,b] where 'a' represents age of member of club and 'b' represents the handicap of the member. The task is to categorize the member into senior if his/her age is greater than or equal to 55 and handicap is less than 7 else the others are to be categorized as open. 

I tried:

'code'
for i in range(0,len(list_a)):
       if list_a[i,0]>=55 and list_a[i,1] >7:
                category.append('Senior')
       else:
               category.append('Open')
'code'

Sorry I'm not used to stack overflow's comment

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to do,

```py
>>> l = [[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
>>> category  = []
>>> for i in l:
        if i[0]>=55 and i[1]>7:
            category.append('Senior')
        else:
            category.append("Open")

>>> category
['Open', 'Open', 'Senior', 'Open', 'Open', 'Senior']
```